# Is it possible to figure out the inorder traversal of a tree if the post order traversal is given?

Tags: c, tree, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

Give Post Order Traversal of a Tree:

```
d f e b g l j k h c a
```

Expected In Order Traversal of the same Tree:

```
d b f e a g c l j h k
```

Is it possible to derive the In Order Traversal of a Tree programmatically given the Post Order Traversal of the same tree?

Comment: "...got the proper answer." ? Was that supposed to say "didn't get the proper answer." ?

Comment: It is impossible to figure out "the" inorder traversal from a given postorder traversal, because there might be many variations as a post ordering is not enough to identify a tree.

Comment: If the tree is a binary searh tree, then yes

Comment: it's a binary search tree.

Comment: Sorry my bad, didn't notice the tags. In the first phase, you can iterate through the postorder traversal nodes in **reverse order** and construct the binary search tree. In the second phase, you have the tree, just perform its inorder traversal.

Comment: @SelçukCihan I totally believe you but could you provide a source?